# Как можно указатель преобразовать в число? С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Я делаю функцию для преобразования адресов, на которые указывают указатели, в HEX строку с последующим выводом. Не спрашивайте почему я не могу воспользоваться `std::cout << std::hex`. Просто хочу сделать сам в целях обучения. Проблема в том, что я никак не могу придумать способ перебрать адрес, на который указывает указатель, по битам. Как можно адрес преобразовать в число? `reinterpret_cast`, но разве его использование не прямой путь к ошибкам, да и вообще сработает ли?

Comment: Ну для таких целей `reinterpret_cast` вполне себе годный вариант. Главное кастовать в `std::uintptr_t`, который гарантировано будет иметь подходящий размер